# Mutable objects in python and constants

Tags: python

I have a class which contains data as attributes and which has a method to return a tuple containing these attributes:

```
class myclass(object):
    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def tuple(self):
        return (self.a, self.b, self.c)
```

I use this class essentially as a tuple where the items (attributes) can be modified/read through their attribute name. Now I would like to create objects of this class, which would be constants and have pre-defined attribute values, which I could then assign to a variable/mutable object, thereby initializing this variable object's attributes to match the constant object, while at the same time retaining the ability to modify the attributes' values. For example I would like to do this:

```
constant_object = myclass(1,2,3)
variable_object = constant_object
variable_object.a = 999
```

Now of course this doesn't work in python, so I am wondering what is the best way to get this kind of functionality?

Comment: Why not just `copy` your `constant_object` into `variable_object`?

Comment: Obviously `constant_object` isn't actually constant, but… how could you expect Python to magically figure that out from the name of the variable?

Comment: @abarnert: really? My python3.3.3 changes both

Comment: The `=` assignment in Python doesn't "copy" anything, it just assigns the same value to another name. And it's not an operator that you can overload. There is no way that `v` and `c` could possibly refer to different objects after you write `v = c`, because `v = c` _means_ that they refer to the same object.

Comment: Meanwhile, there's nothing "constant" about your `constant_object`. So when you put the same value into `variable_object`, it's still not constant. So, despite what the question says, `variable_object.a = 999` actually works just fine.

Comment: @abarnert That's exactly right. How did you write such nonsense first? :-) BTW I think "doesn't work" in the question means "doesn't do what I want" (affects `constant_object.a`), not "throws an error".

Comment: @delnan: I edited my original comment four times until it stopped making sense. :) What I was trying to say is that if you have a "constant" instance and a "variable" instance, there's nothing stopping you from changing the variable instance (but also nothing stopping you from changing the constant once); so if you have just one instance, the exact same thing is true. But that was a confusing way to come at the answer.

Comment: As a side note, if you're going to have a method named `tuple` that turns this into a tuple (and you don't want it to be a `namedtuple` in the first place, for some reason), you might also want to make it iterable. If you add an `def __iter__(self): yield from (self.a, self.b, self.c)` (slightly more wordy in 2.x), then you can write `tuple(myobj)` instead of `myobj.tuple()`—and you can also write `list(myobj)` and `deque(myobj)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I would like to create objects of this class, which would be constants and have pre-defined attribute values, which I could then assign to a variable/mutable object, thereby initializing this variable object's attributes to match the constant object,

Well, you can't have that. Assignment in Python doesn't initialize anything. It doesn't copy or create anything. All it does is give a new name to the existing value.

If you want to initialize an object, the way to do that in Python is to call the constructor.

So, with your existing code:

```
new_object = myclass(old_object.a, old_object.b, old_object.c)
```

If you look at most built-in and stdlib classes, it's a lot more convenient. For example:

```
a = set([1, 2, 3])
b = set(a)
```

How do they do that? Simple. Just define an `__init__` method that can be called with an existing instance. (In the case of `set`, this comes for free, because a `set` can be initialized with any iterable, and `set`s are iterable.)

If you don't want to give up your existing design, you're going to need a pretty clumsy `__init__`, but it's at least *doable*. Maybe this:

```
_sentinel = object()
def __init__(myclass_or_a, b=_sentinel, c=_sentinel):
    if isinstance(a, myclass):
        self.a, self.b, self.c = myclass_or_a.a, myclass_or_a.b, myclass_or_a.c
    else:
        self.a, self.b, self.c = myclass_or_a, b, c
```

… plus some error handling to check that `b is _sentinel` in the first case and that it isn't in the other case.

---

So, however you do it:

```
constant_object = myclass(1,2,3)
variable_object = myclass(constant_object)
variable_object.a = 999
```

Comment: In many cases, `None` fills the role of `_sentinel` just fine, which makes code prettier.

Comment: This is an interesting option, then my 3 line code example above would look like: constant_object = myclass(1,2,3); variable_object = myclass(constant_object)...I do wish there was a way to define a given object as constant/immutable though as then it would be more elegant with just variable_object = constant_object

Comment: @delnan: I used to always use `None` and add a footnote at the end explaining that you can use a custom sentinel if you need it, but every time I did that, someone commented that `None` can be a valid value for many cases. So now I use a custom sentinel, and someone comments that `None` is a perfectly good sentinel for many cases. :) But I think having one in the answer and the other in a comment works nicely.

Comment: @user3208430: Yes, exactly. I edited your example into the answer to make it more obvious (since code in comments is unreadable in SO).

Comment: @user3208430: For the other part of your question: there are (slightly hacky) ways to make different kinds of things immutable in Python, but that's usually a bad idea. The cost of copying 3 ints around is nothing, so just make a copy. If you want lots of enforced-immutable instances around, what you really want is probably two separate types—like `frozenset` and `set`, `tuple` and `list`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
import copy

class myclass(object):
    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def tuple(self):
        return (self.a, self.b, self.c)

constant_object = myclass(1,2,3)
variable_object = copy.deepcopy(constant_object)
variable_object.a = 999
print constant_object.a
print variable_object.a
```

Output:

```
1
999
```

Answer (score 1):

Deepcopying is not entirely necessary in this case, because of the way you've setup your `tuple` method

```
class myclass(object):
    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def tuple(self):
        return (self.a, self.b, self.c)

constant_object = myclass(1,2,3)
variable_object = myclass(*constant_object.tuple())
variable_object.a = 999

>>> constant_object.a
1
>>> variable_object.a
999
```

Usually (as others have suggested), you'd want to deepcopy. This creates a brand new object, with no ties to the object being copied. However, given that you are using only `int`s, deepcopy is overkill. You're better off doing a shallow copy. As a matter of fact, it might even be faster to call the class constructor on the parameters of the object you already have, seeing as these parameters are `int`s. This is why I suggested the above code.

Comment: This will not for mutable objects like lists, dicts etc.

Comment: Note that this is essentially a class-specific way to make a *shallow* copy (also implemented as `copy.copy()`), which has different semantic from a deep copy (as implemented by `copy.deepcopy()`).

Comment: Yup. This works only because of the specific way in which this class is setup

Comment: I don't think the OP necessarily wants a deep copy. (In fact, I'm pretty sure that, even if he does, he doesn't _know_ he wants one…) So the fact that this won't deep-copy mutable a, b, and c isn't really a problem, as long as it's noted.

Comment: @abarnert: good point. I've just added some text to that effect